# nohup redirection command difference

Tags: linux, unix

What is the difference between these 2 below lines?

```
nohup $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh $CATALINA_HOME 2> /dev/null &

nohup $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh $CATALINA_HOME > /dev/null &
```

I've these lines in 2 of my projects having Tomcat server. One of them is having 2> & other one is just with > symbol.

Appreciate youe help!

**Note:** The line with 2> if ran in CentOS runs fine but the other one gives warning: "nohup: redirecting stderr to stdout"

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both redirect to `/dev/null` the first one redirects `stderr` the second one redirects `stdout`.

More on that: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html, also a few examples always from tldp http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html

Side note: if you want to redirect both `stdout` and `stderr` you could do:

```
nohup $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh $CATALINA_HOME &> /dev/null &
```

Comment: When I run the 2nd line on Red Hat 5.7 OS, it does not give me any warning but when the same is run on CentOS 6.4, it gives warning "nohup: redirecting stderr to stdout", how can I avoid this warning in CentOS?

Comment: I've updated my answer, look at the last command, that redirects both `stdout` and `stderr`

Comment: `&>` is a non-standard mechanism.  It redirects both streams in some shells (eg bash) and behaves completely differently in others (eg dash, which conforms to the sh language specifications and treats the `&` as a separate token, running the command in the background and then truncating the file to which you intended to direct output.)

Comment: Then it depends on the sh of the OP. Thanks for that though.

Comment: Quick question: Why red hat OS does not give the warning message for 2nd line where as centOS gives warning?