# Difference between nohup vs simple output redirect

Tags: bash, redirect, nohup

What is the difference between the following methods of launching background jobs?

- `./long_job.sh > logfile &`
- `nohup ./long_job.sh > logfile &`

(by default, option 2  this will print to `nohup.out` or you can redirect to a filename of your choice).

What are the advantages of `nohup`? I tested the following shell script as a proxy for `long_job.sh` and exited the terminal (with `ctrl-D`)

```
while [ 1==1 ]; do
    jot -r -c 4 A Z | rs -g  0 4
    echo $$ # Echo pid
    sleep 2
done
```

There is a [nohup question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575142/nohup-redirection-command-difference) with similar title, but it asks about difference between redirection of stdout and stderr

**EDIT**: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595374/whats-the-difference-between-nohup-and-ampersand) does not talk about explicit file redirect. Without redirect, when shell quits, the child process dies because it does not have stdout to print to. But *with* redirect it does not need the shell window to be open. Operationally, both approaches above achieve the same outcome (which is run the job even after terminal closes). My question about was the difference between the two approaches.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between nohup and ampersand](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595374/whats-the-difference-between-nohup-and-ampersand)

Comment: Why not read the manual page for nohup?

Comment: @EdHeal I couldn't find information to understand the *difference* between the two approaches in my man pages.

Comment: From the manual page of nohup "If standard input is a terminal, redirect it from /dev/nul" " run a command immune to hangups" both not true when run on the command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in the listed approaches depends on the status of `huponexit` variable in your shell. The status of this variable is obtained by `shopt | grep huponexit`.

When `huponexit` is `off`, the listed approaches are operationally identical -- Both redirect standard output to `logfile` and continue to run  upon exiting the shell.

When `huponexit` is `on`, (`shopt -s huponexit`), the shell sends the hangup (hup) signal to child processes which causes it to terminate. The `nohup` approach continues to work.

Since you may not always have privileges to control `huponexit`, the `nohup` approach is more failsafe for long background jobs.